# Iniciando o componente Windows Media Player em fullscreen

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Quando a aplicação com Windows Media Player é aberta (Windows Forms) sempre tenho que apertar no botão *fullscreen* para maximizar o vídeo que está em execução e gostaria que o mesmo já iniciasse em tela cheia.

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 1):

Basta fazer isto no formulário principal:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    this.TopMost = true;
    this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/WinForms/FullScreen.cs).

Comment: Isso dai expande todo o form eu gostaria apenas o componente axmediaplayer. ja usei esse codigo para outra coisa, ate agora sem resolver isso.

Comment: Você não pode colocar *fullscreen* só um componente, o que você pode fazer é criar um outro formulário onde o seu componente ocupa todo ele e aí o formulário fica *fullscreen*. Sem este truque você não consegue resolver.